# Resizing Small Photos By Merging It With A Transparent Layer

Tags: php, image, merge

I am working with some historical photos, and there is no standard size. Resizing is causing many of them to look smooshed, so they are not scaling correctly. These are in a Bootstrap carousel, so if the height is not the same, you get a jumpy page. So I got thinking, why not keep the original size, and then merge it, to a transparent layer, that is the correct size.

I know I need to at some point convert a JPG to PNG for the transparency to work, what I do not know, if such an approach will do what I want, keep the image to scale, stop the page bounce, and still keep the whole page responsive.

for example, if the main image is 700x300, and my transparent image is 800x600, will the merge be 800x600 with the "fill" being transparent. Or is there a whole different way to do this?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: The approach sounds reasonable - maybe post some images and numbers....

Answer (score 0):

This idea does work, but refined my thoughts. What I ended up doing to save me a lot of recoding, was to make a transparent image of the size needed for the DIV that holds the image. This kept every thing as it should with just the smallest bounce, and that is from the caption, which will be easy to fix.

I know there have been a lot of posts, in many places about how to do this with the Bootstrap slider, so here is just another approach, that is simple. If you want it to be a clear background make sure you make it a PNG, if you want a color background, make it the color and can be JPG, GIF, or PNG.

Thanks,

Dave